# How do I view the duration of MP4 files in Explorer on XP?

Tags: windows-xp, windows-explorer, mp4

When displaying the Duration column in a folder window with MP4 videos, it is blank. I am aware that there is no native support for this filetype in Windows XP. [This](https://superuser.com/questions/252051/propertiesdetails-run-time-length/252052) answer is related, but only gives very general advice (I tried installing the program suggested, but you have to open the file to view the statistics). I've also tried installing the Haali media splitter, though I'm no video expert, and I don't want to randomly start installing buggy codec packs either. Is there a way to do what I need?

Footnote: This is not directly relevant to the question at hand, but [Media Preview by BabelSoft](http://www.babelsoft.net/products.htm) has been working *amazingly* to show thumbnails for video files not natively supported on XP (works on later versions [too](https://superuser.com/questions/496689/how-to-enable-thumbnail-previews-for-my-non-standard-mp4-avi-mov-mkv-video-fil)).

Comment: If this is a 64-bit version of XP, see if the problem occurs using the 32-bit Explorer, which is invoked like this : `C:\windows\syswow64\explorer.exe /separate`.

Comment: It's 32-bit, and it's not exactly a problem, more of a needed feature.

Comment: Try right-click>properties??

Comment: @RahulBasu Please reread the question.

Answer (score 2):

You could try on [explorer2](http://zabkat.com/index.htm)

From the website :

> xplorer² is a desktop file manager combining the simplicity of windows
>   explorer with the speed and efficiency of traditional dual pane
>   orthodox file managers, helping you be productive with your documents,
>   pictures, music, source code and other files.

I downloaded for my xp and managed to get the mp4 files by adding length column through it,

Working proof :

[image]

Comment: It's paid, but it appears to do the job, technically...

Comment: There's a free version available here:
http://zabkat.com/x2lite.htm

Answer (score 0):

In the registry, go to

```
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT
.mp4
ShellEx
```

Create a Key in there named {BB2E617C-0920-11d1-9A0B-00C04FC2D6C1}
with a date value of {c5a40261-cd64-4ccf-84cb-c394da41d590}

So then you have :
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT
.mp4
ShellEx
{BB2E617C-0920-11d1-9A0B-00C04FC2D6C1}

and inside here ^^^^^^^^^
you have a new string value that looks like:

(Default) Reg_SZ {c5a40261-cd64-4ccf-84cb-c394da41d590}

Originally found [here](http://forums.steves-digicams.com/sanyo/92606-mp4-thumbnails-xp-explorer.html)

Comment: These are instructions on how to display thumbnails, a problem that I've already solved. It does not answer the question.

Comment: Sorry, that's why I posted the link to where I got it from.

Comment: @Bigbio2002 - You should update your question.  There is no way Everett would have known that.